# In R , Why predicted values of a neural network keep changing everytime when we train the network?

Tags: r, neural-networks

Everytime we train the neural network in R (under neuralnet package) for the same data,it predicts different values which aren't the same as predicted earlier ... Any way to solve this issue ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably some randomization involved in initialization and/or training - you may want to read through the references provided in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neuralnet/neuralnet.pdf).

Try setting the random number generator's seed prior to training, by using `set.seed()`. ([Just don't simply use `set.seed(123)` ;-).](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/205961/1352))